# Match string segments in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

In python, I'm trying to get a string like this:

```
abcd[_FILE:foo.txt_]efghi[_FILE:bar.txt_]jklm[_FILE:foo2.txt_]
```

to match:

```
['foo.txt', 'bar.txt', 'foo2.txt']
```

But I don't know how to match full string segments instead of single individual characters.  Does anyone know how I can write an regular expression to match '[*FILE' instead of '[', '*', 'F', 'I', .... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

regx = re.compile('[a-z]+\[_FILE:(.*?)_\]')


ch = 'abcd[_FILE:foo.txt_]efghi[_FILE:bar.txt_]jklm[_FILE:foo2.txt_] '

print regx.findall(ch)
```

[ is used in regex's patterns to define a set, so when you want to symbolize a character '[' in a pattern, you must escape it

Comment: Thanks, the non-greedy *? was exactly what I needed. I modified it slightly to fit my actual specifications: `re.compile('.*\[_FILE=(.*?)_\]') ;` So it can match when there are no preceding characters and the characters can be non-alphanumeric.

Comment: Correction, I ended up using:

`re.compile('[^\[\]\_]*\[_FILE=(.*?)_\]') ;`

Comment: @Christopher Dorian Mmmmm... I doubt the ``'[^\[\]\_]*`` part of the pattern to be really useful. It doesn't define a group to be matched, so it can be removed without problem. And the star * says that this part is optional in the analyzed string, so it can't be considered as an help for the regex motor to find where the match(es) will occur. If you want to specify that the character before the boudary ``[_`` must not be any character of the list _ , [ , ]  it is best to use negative lookbehind assertion: ``'(?<=[^[\]_])\[_FILE:(.*?)_\]'``

Comment: @Christopher Dorian If you want to specify something concerning the two (optional ?) preceding characters , it is a bit more complicated because of the fact that lookbehind assertions don't accept variable length of sub-pattern in them, in Python. 

// By the way, ``[[\]_]`` can be written like that because the second **[** can't be interpreted as the opening bracket of a set. Concerning **_** , it has not to be escaped outside a set , nor in a set definition.

Answer (score 4):

Try this pattern:

```
import re
text = 'abcd[_FILE:foo.txt_]efghi[_FILE:bar.txt_]jklm[_FILE:foo2.txt_]'
pattern = re.compile('FILE:([\w\.]+)_\]')
pattern.findall(text)
```

Output:

```
['foo.txt', 'bar.txt', 'foo2.txt']
```

Comment: This answer is bad. 1) the more there are anchors in a pattern, the best it is. Here, why not use '[_' before FILE, and why not use ']' after FILE ? , since it is obvious they are always in the string 2) the '?' to make the regex ungreedy has been forgot

Comment: @eyquem - I tried to give a minimal pattern to match the input, but I realize there are several ways to write a pattern for this match. No worries. :-)

Comment: Your regex works, in fact, but not for an orthodox reason. First, the regex motor finds a match of ``[\w\.]`` with ``'foo.txt_'`` , then it verifies that it is followed by a character ``'_'``; since it isn't true, it comes back and tries if ``[\w\.]`` matches with the string less the last character, that is to say with ``'foo.txt'`` : this time it's right, because it is really followed by a character ``'_'``. But it's a weird process. I think it is better to put a ``'?'`` in the pattern to cut the greediness of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
print re.findall('FILE:(\w+\.txt)', mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall), it will find all non-overlapping matches of a pattern in a string, and return it as a list of strings.

```
import re
re.findall('_FILE:(.*?)_', string)
```

Comment: A file's may have a character _ in it so your regex will stop before having matched all the name